# Why isn't Adam Optimizer working?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am learning how to use optimizers to train a model in Tensor Flow. 
So, I built a linear model, created a toy data set and trained the linear model with `AdamOptimizer` and `GradientDescentOptimizer`.

This is my snippet:

```
# Training a linear model with Adam optimizer

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Training dataset
Xs_ = np.random.random(48).reshape(12, 4)
Yt_ = np.random.random(12).reshape(12, 1)

Xs2_ = np.array([1,  2,  3,  4, 
                 5,  6,  7,  8,
                 9,  10, 11, 12,
                 13, 14, 15, 16]).reshape(4, 4)
Yt2_ = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]).reshape(4, 1)

# inference
Xs = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, 4), dtype=tf.float32)
W = tf.Variable(np.zeros((4,1), dtype=np.float32))
b = tf.Variable(np.ones((1, 1), dtype=np.float32))
Ys = tf.add(tf.matmul(Xs, W), b)

Yt = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float32)

# loss
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(Yt, Ys))

# training
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-4, beta1=0.99, epsilon=0.1)
optimizer2 = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)
train2 = optimizer2.minimize(loss)


# Executing the graph with Adam Optimizer
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    feed_dict = {Yt: Yt2_, Xs: Xs2_}
    sess.run(train, feed_dict)

    print "Adam trained vars (W, b)", sess.run([W, b], feed_dict)

# Executing the graph with Gradient Descent Optimizer
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    feed_dict = {Yt: Yt2_, Xs: Xs2_}
    sess.run(train2, feed_dict)

    print "GD trained vars (W, b)", sess.run([W, b], feed_dict)
```

---

And here is the output I see:

```
Adam trained vars (W, b) [array([[  9.07433059e-05],
       [  9.14905831e-05],
       [  9.21262108e-05],
       [  9.26734720e-05]], dtype=float32), array([[ 1.00004864]], dtype=float32)]
GD trained vars (W, b) [array([[ 0.31      ],
       [ 0.34      ],
       [ 0.37      ],
       [ 0.39999998]], dtype=float32), array([[ 1.02999997]], dtype=float32)]
```

I experimented with different learning rates, betas and epsilons; but somehow AdamOptimizer isn't updating the variables (`W` and `b`).

I also saw a few people are separately calculating gradients and then applying them to the variables, instead of directly using `AdamOptimizer().minimize(_loss_function_)`.

I am new to TensorFlow and I am not sure if I am missing something. Please give in some insights. Thanks!

Comment: In both cases, you are executing just one step of Gradient descent. Adam has by default a big momentum (inertia), so it takes a while in order to accelerate. SGD, on the other hand, accelerates instantly, as it has no momentum. Execute more iterations and you will see W to update accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful! Please add this as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both cases, you are executing just one step of Gradient descent. Adam has by default a big momentum (inertia), so it takes a while in order to accelerate. SGD, on the other hand, accelerates instantly, as it has no momentum. Execute more iterations and you will see the value of W to increase accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

From the output, the variables are updated. You initialize `W` with zeros and `b` with ones and clearly you see that they changed. I'm not sure why you are thinking that they did not change. Maybe you think the change is too small? Your learning rate is also smaller (which is uncommon - normally you can use a bigger learning rate compared to SGD). Despite that, look at the formula of Adam -- it uses momentum for both the gradient and the squared gradient, which is initialized with zero. So it takes a few steps for faster/bigger updates. Anyway, your code looks correct.

Comment: I see slight difference, but shouldn't the values of  AdamOptimizer's `W` be somewhat closer to GD's `W`? Since, I am training both with same sets of inputs?

Comment: Thank you! The results are consistent after training for higher epochs.